# TradingView's ‘undeclared identifier’ error in pine

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I try to edit script ver.2 and i dont now how to rewrite to ver.4 for public

Bellow errors:

```
line 11: Undeclared identifier 'jump';
line 12: Undeclared identifier 'jump';
line 13: Undeclared identifier 'jump';
line 14: Undeclared identifier 'jump';
line 15: Undeclared identifier 'upperlinemark';
line 15: Undeclared identifier 'lineset';
line 16: Undeclared identifier 'bellowlinemark';
line 16: Undeclared identifier 'lineset';
line 17: Undeclared identifier 'upperlinemark';
line 17: Undeclared identifier 'bellowlinemark';
line 17: Undeclared identifier 'lineset';
line 18: Undeclared identifier 'upperlinemark';
line 18: Undeclared identifier 'bellowlinemark';
line 18: Undeclared identifier 'lineset';
line 19: Undeclared identifier 'firstplot';
line 19: Undeclared identifier 'thirdplot';
line 19: Undeclared identifier 'lineset';
line 20: Undeclared identifier 'secondplot';
line 20: Undeclared identifier 'fourthplot';
line 20: Undeclared identifier 'lineset'
```

Help me please, i will be so thankful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable in its declaration. You need to declare it first.

Here is how you can fix that issue. You have

```
graphgo = 0.0
graphback = 0.0
graphgo := close[1]>graphgo[1]? max(go,graphgo[1]) : go
graphback := close[1]<graphback[1]? min(back,graphback[1]) : back
```

Also, you need to use the `color` namespace for the colors.

So, change lines like this:

```
lineset = jump == 1 ? lime : red
```

To this:

```
lineset = jump == 1 ? color.lime : color.red
```

Comment: Look, i edit question, there is still issues

Comment: It's the same thing. You cannot use a variable in its declaration. You need to declare it first.